# The weak limit of a sequence of infinitely divisible probability measures is infinitely divisible

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $\{\mu_n\}_n$ be a sequence of infinitely divisible probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $\mu_n \xrightarrow{\text{weak}} \mu$ for some probability measure $\mu$. I want to prove that $\mu$ is also infinitely divisible.

### My attempt:

If $\mu_n \xrightarrow{\text{weak}} \mu$, then ([by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f(x) \mu_n(d x) = \int f(x) \mu(d x)$ for any continuous, bounded $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$. In particular, this holds for $f(x) = e^{i(u, x)}$ for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$. This implies that
\begin{equation}
        \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\phi_{\mu_n}(u) = \phi_\mu(u).
    \end{equation}
Then, for any $m \geq 1$,
\begin{equation}
        \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \big( \phi_{\mu_n} \big)^{1/m}(u) = \big( \phi_\mu (u)\big)^{1/m}
    \end{equation}
Since each $\phi_{\mu_n}$ is infinitely divisible, $(\phi_{\mu_n})^{1/m}$ is a characteristic function for any $m \in \mathbb{N}, m \geq 1$.

It is clear to see that $\phi^{1/m}_\mu$ is continuous at zero ($\phi_\mu$ is continuous at zero). Hence by [Levy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem), $\phi_\mu^{1/m}$ is a characteristic function for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$. So $\mu$ is infintely divisible.

Is my proof correct? This is an exercise (1.2.12) in Applebaum's book on Levy processes.

Comment: This proof  is not valid. It assumes that $n-$ th root is a continuous function on the complex plane, but this is not even a well a defined function. You can refer to Chung's book for a proper proof.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy, that's helpful. Thanks for reference too, I'll spend some more time on it first :)